# Looking for a more efficient way to avoid apps that require creating online accounts

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Here's an example of a recurring problem: I'm looking for a simple GPS-based pace-keeping app to keep me on track timewise while cycling, running, hiking, etc.  So I find a candidate app via the play store, if it's not free I buy it, then I install it and run it for the first time.  Then I discover that its use requires creating an account at some online site.  I find this unacceptable, so I delete the app, and go back to searching.

Of course, the whole maybe-purchase-install-start-uninstall cycle gets to be very time-consuming when the probability of success (i.e. finding an app that does not require an online account) is low.

In my ideal world, there would be a way to filter search results to exclude apps that require setting up an online account, but I'm not holding my breath for this feature.

Is there a way to identify those apps that require an online account before installing them?

Comment: You could Google the app/company name and check their website (if they have one). There's no way to filter apps in Play unfortunately, as developers do not have to flag if their app requires an account to be made.